# YouTube v3 ASP.net API works on local IIS7 but not on shared hosting site

Tags: youtube-data-api

The following works great on my local IIS and return videos. When I run it on my GoDaddy shared hosting website (using https), it returns "This page can't be displayed". My code is below and I have isolated the problem down to this statement:

// Execute search
  SearchListResponse searchListResponse = searchListRequest.Execute();

I have searched but cannot find solution and even called GoDaddy for help but no joy yet. Hope someone can help resolve.

Here's the source code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Reflection; 
using System.Threading; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

//using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2; 
using Google.Apis.Services; 
using Google.Apis.Upload; 
using Google.Apis.Util.Store; 
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3; 
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data; 

public void runSearch(string query)
{
    try
    {
        // Create YouTube Service
        YouTubeService youTubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = "xxxx",
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        SearchResource.ListRequest searchListRequest = youTubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = query;
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 15;
        searchListRequest.Type = "video";

        // Execute search
        SearchListResponse searchListResponse = searchListRequest.Execute();

        ...

}
```